# Getting 3 last fb posts & tweets

Tags: facebook, twitter, joomla

I need to display the latest 3 Facebook posts (from my Facebook account) and 3 tweets (from my Twitter account) on my Joomla website. Any help (code?) will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good start

http://extensions.joomla.org/

Or http://www.facebook.com/badges/ and http://twitter.com/widgets/html_widget

Both of the above link create the required code - you just have to create a module using mod_wrapper and dump the code in.

Comment: Can I use facebook & twitter's API?